# how to add condition in kendo grid view

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to show/hide remove(delete( icon)based on condition.for ex **var a=2,var b=2;if(a=b) need to show the icon.But a!=b means hide the delete icon**.How to do this?

```
{
  command: {
              template: kendo.template($("#remove").html())                
            }, title: " ", width: "40px"
 }

<script id="remove" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <a href="" onclick="remove(this); return false;">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/delete_icon.gif")" alt="Remove item" />
    </a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript in your templates:

```
<script id="remove" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    # var a=2; var b=2;#
    # if(a==b){ #
    <a href="" onclick="remove(this); return false;">
        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/delete_icon.gif")" alt="Remove item" />
    </a>
    # } #
</script>
```

Check [`Kendo UI Templates Overview`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview) for more detailed examples and different *Template Syntax* of kendo:

1. `Render literal values: #= #`
2. `Render HTML-encoded values: #: #`
3. `Execute arbitrary JavaScript code: # if(...){# ... #}#`